# Loop through Iframe using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have create one automate program, for that I require to iterate through every frame document and set some input.

I iterate it with below function, which is working fine, but in below URL it gave me Access Denied error.

http://usacarhire.com/

Code I am using to iterate through every frame and Iframe.

```
var i = new Array;
var t = '';

var IFrameDoc;

function GetAllFrame(a, n) 
{
t = '';

try {

    for (i[n] = 0; i[n] < a.length; i[n]++) 

{try{
var oIframe = a[i[n]];

            IFrameDoc = oIframe.document;

            alert(IFrameDoc.body.outerHTML);
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert("Internal Error" + e.message + " - " + a[i[n]].frames.length);
        }

        if (a[i[n]].frames.length) t += GetAllFrame(a[i[n]].frames, n + 1);

    }
}
catch (e) {
    alert("External Error" + e.message);
}
return t;}
```

Comment: Is the iFrame that you get Access Denied in a remote location or on your machine?

Comment: Yes, It is. I know its a cross domain thing, but I don't know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

If the other iFrames aren't yours then it can not be solved, you can not override the cross origin policy.
If you do own both of them what you can do is use HTML5's postMessage API to "talk" between the iFrame and the parent window, but I don't believe that is what you want.
If you do, leave a comment and I will edit my answer.

Comment: Guy, is there any way from that I can get or set details of Iframe?

Comment: It all depends if the iFrame is under the same domain as the parent window.
If not, most times it won't be and thus wouldn't be possible and then you will have to use HTML5 postMessage or some other forms, you can have a look at this blogpost that seems useful,
http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes